# move redmine database to another instance

Tags: database, instance, move, redmine, migrate

I have redmine 2.5.3 installed on a virtual machine ( [See Martin Denizet blog for HowTo install it](http://martin-denizet.com/install-redmine-2-5-x-git-subversion-ubuntu-14-04-apache2-rvm-passenger/) )
Now, I want to move previous redmine DB (version 1.3) to this virtual machine.
Both of redmine versions are in working , but virtual machine is not in production environment yet.

I have tried changing the $REDMINE/config/database.yml to the production env, but I got "Internal server error" after refreshing the 2.5.3 main page.

How this is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow *instruction* in *[RedmineUpgrade_WikiPage](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineUpgrade)* as the *main solution.*

Another Solution is to setup an instance of redmine (any version whom you want and in any type of machine whom you have, doesn't matter Virtual or Bare) which is described in *[Martin Denizet Blog -> HowTo install redmine](http://martin-denizet.com/install-redmine-2-5-x-git-subversion-ubuntu-14-04-apache2-rvm-passenger/)*, Then:

- **Create a Back Up**

```
    $ mysqldump --host=localhost -uredmine -p \ 
  --default-characterset=utf8 db_name > redmine_db.dump
```

- **Set Database**

  Set the main database information in $REDMINE_DIR/config/database.yml
  for example :

```
    production:
      adapter: mysql2 
      database: redmine
      host: 10.0.0.151
      username: dev
      password: "my_password"
      encoding: utf8
```

- **Migrate**

```
    cd $REDMINE_DIR
    bundle exec rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production
    bundle exec rake redmine:plugins:migrate RAILS_ENV=production
```

- **Reset Admin Password *(optional)***

```
RAILS_ENV=production script/rails r 'user = User.find(:first, :conditions => {:admin => true}) ; user.password, user.password_confirmation = "password"; user.save!'
```

Celebration Time :D,
 Now, You can login in the new instance as *admin* by *password*.